# Rebuild Index Task Breaks Compliation of Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a maintenance plan that runs on my SQL Server 2008 server every morning before business hours. It was put in place a few years ago to help with some performance issues. The problem that I am seeing is that after that rebuild index finishes, there is a stored procedure in one of the databases that will go from taking nine seconds to run to taking seven minutes to run.

The solution I have found to fix it is to open SQL Management Studio and run:

```
EXEC sp_recompile N'stored_proc_name';
EXEC stored_prod_name @userId=579
```

After I run that, the SP fixes itself and goes back to running under nine seconds.

I've tried a couple of different paths to automate this, but it will only work if I run it from my computer through management studio. I tried to wrap it up in a little C# executable that ran a few minutes after the rebuild index job completes, but that didn't work. I also tried creating a SQL job to run it on the server after the rebuild index job completes, but that didn't work either. It has to be run from management studio.

So, two questions:

1. How can I stop rebuild index from breaking my SPs, or,
2. Any ideas on how or why my quick fix will only work in a very specific situation?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Are you after a quick fix or after a more thorough solution? You should probably tune the proc to not have plan issues. There are a few common solutions to that like `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` and `OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN`.

Comment: Actually, it isn't that the "rebuild index" task is *breaking* the stored procedure; it is that it is causing the query plan cache to become invalidated, and immediately after that a new query-plan is becoming cached with biased data, causing a sub-optimal query-plan to be used for the bulk of the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like standard parameter sniffing / parameter-based query-plan caching. The trick here is usually to use the `OPTIMIZE FOR` / `UNKNOWN` hint - either for the specific parameter that is causing the problem, or simply for all parameters. This makes it much less likely that a parameter-value with biased distribution will negatively impact the system for other values. A more extreme option (more useful when using command-text, not so useful when using stored procedures) is to embed the value directly into the TSQL rather than using a parameter. This... has impact, however, and should be used with caution.

In your case, I suspect that adding:

```
OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@userId UNKNOWN))
```

to the end of your query will fix it.